# "I told you earlier" or "I told before"?

Tags: adverbs

Could you tell me if I have to use *earlier* or *before* after *tell* in the following context.

> Person A: why didn't you tell me that Kate and John are going to get married.
>
> Person B: Actually, I told you **earlier**/**before**. A few times.

Are both possible? If so, then is there any difference in meaning between the two?

Comment: The correct response to the question would be, "Actually, I *did* tell you." Both "before" and "earlier" are implied in the exchange.

Comment: Try it in your own language. For example: in Spanish. Lo vi antes//Lo vi mas temprano. Hmm. Why would English be any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of OP's examples are syntactically fine, and they mean exactly the same thing (as would adverbial ***already*** before the verb). From [an answer to this same question on Quora...](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-before-earlier)

> ***Before*** and ***earlier*** can act as ***adverbs of time***, but also have their original functions as a ***preposition*** and a ***comparative adjective*** respectively.

But note that whereas ***earlier*** always involves some kind of "time-based" comparison, the preposition ***before*** is also often used to indicate a "spatial" relationship / positioning. Hence the well-worn joke *"How dare you break wind before the Queen!", "I'm sorry, I didn't know it was her turn!"* (juxtaposing the two meanings ***before = in front of, in the presence of*** and ***before = in advance of, earlier***).

Comment: Apparently unlike you, I don't believe there ***is*** a "difference as used by OP". But regardless of whether anyone finds the joke *funny*, I think it's highly relevant in terms of showing a familiar context where ***before*** can be very different to ***earlier***.

Comment: earlier refers to a time on a clock whereas before is non-specific and does absolutely not refer to **time on a clock**. I told him before (three months ago). I told  him earlier [today, at noon.] No difference??

Comment: You said all that in your answer, but I didn't accept your distinction there either. Although it's true that ***before*** can reference *spatial* as well as chronological "relative positioning", that doesn't to me imply any semantic difference between the two terms *within* the chronological scope. And obviously there are no *syntactic* differences in OP's exact context, since they *are* interchangeable.

Comment: Such bad faith. Unbelievable. "Before" refers to the number of times someone does something. I have told you before [one time, twice, three times etc.] That is not "chronology".

Comment: <sigh> There's nothing "syntactically incorrect" about using forms like [***twice earlier***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22twice+earlier%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03AG6mBdVYAgTIsBn0qbJTmfq-MWw:1591375583106&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX69aCkOvpAhVGXMAKHXrnB3UQpwUIIQ&biw=1493&bih=780&dpr=1.13) rather than ***twice before***, if that's what's bothering you. It's just that of idiomatically we *tend* to make the latter choice. Certainly the word ***before*** has no inherent connection to "[preceding] occurrence **counts**".

Comment: Not at all. Not at all. It is not the bloody grammar. It's the meaning. The two mean different things. I didn't tell you that earlier (East Coast US)  but I certainly told  you before!

Comment: The only difference I'm aware of between ***I didn't tell you that before*** and ***I didn't tell you that earlier*** is that idiomatically the former is about 10x more common. I've no reason to suppose "East Coast US" speakers in general should have any different opinions in this matter.

Comment: I didn't tell you **earlier** (today, **my time is East Coats US**). But I told you before (on another occasion: yesterday). All **varieties** of English.

Comment: Nah. You've told me ***earlier, before, previously, already,*** and ***repeatedly***. But I still don't buy your distinction.

Comment: Then,  you are frankly deluding yourself, which I did not tell you earlier (today, time-wise) or before (occasion-wise).

Answer (score 1):

1) I told you **before**. [before this time (one time, two times,three times) that I am telling you]

2) I told you **earlier**. [I told  you at 3 o'clock not now at 5 o'clock]

**The word time** does not mean the same in the explanations above.

in 1) it means: tell someone something at a particular moment: **now**, *before now,* after now, at some time = moment

in 2) it means: the time on a clock, the time of day that is earlier than the time of day when the sentence is being said.

1) I told him the story **three times**. The time **before** this, I told it to him in its entirety. But all three times was months ago.

2) I told him the story earlier. That can only refer to clock time.

That is the **semantic difference between the two**.